# How do I fix shocking/lagging movement in this ajax based multiplayer example?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas, lag

EDIT: important, examples must be used in firefox 3+ due to html5 elements.

Hi there,

I'm trying to find out more about the potential of AJAX in a browser based multiplayer game. To do so, I'm testing out movement with AJAX and a space shuttle as a character. This space shuttle is rendered with canvas (html5).

My first version is ready, you can test it out here: [http://ajax.uptowar.com/test3/][1]

Source code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();
$_SESSION['playerid'] = "";
echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ajax test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <meta name="audience" content="all" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">


        //vars
        var presstime = 300; //howlong a button should be hold down for 1 event fire
        var ajaxivtime = 500; //interval at which doAjax is executed, unless a manual request has been send within this time
        var keypressivtime = 50; //interval at which the keypress fire event is fired

        //init vars
        var keysdown = []; //array for what keys are down at a specific moment
        var cobjects = []; //array for all canvas objects
        var oldpress = 0;
        var ajaxrestime = 0;
        var latency = 0;

        //functions
        function isset() {
            var a = arguments;
            var l = a.length;
            var i = 0;
            if (l === 0) { 
                return false;
            }
            while (i != l) {
                if (typeof(a[i]) == 'undefined' || a[i] === null) { 
                    return false; 
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        function keycheck(e) {
            var keynum;
            if (window.event) { //IE
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) { // Netscape // FireFox // Opera
                keynum = e.which;
            }
            if (keysdown.indexOf(keynum) == -1) {
                keysdown.push(keynum);
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateLatency(oldLatencyTime) {
            var curtime = new Date();
            curtime = curtime.getTime();
            if (oldLatencyTime !== 0) {
                latency = curtime - oldLatencyTime;
                document.title = "Latency: " + latency + "ms";
            }
            return true;
        }

        function setAjaxResTime() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            ajaxrestime = curtime.getTime();
            return true;
        }

        function getAjaxResTimeDiff() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            curtime = curtime.getTime();
            return curtime - ajaxrestime;
        }

        function setOldPress() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            oldpress = curtime.getTime();
            return true;
        }

        function getPressTimeDiff() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            curtime = curtime.getTime();
            return curtime - oldpress;
        }

        function searchcobjects(canvasid) {
            indexes = cobjects.length - 1;
            i = 0;
            while (i <= indexes) {
                if (cobjects[i][0] == canvasid) {
                    return i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        function getCurX(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][2];
        }

        function getCurY(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][3];
        }

        function getTarX(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][4];
        }

        function getTarY(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][5];
        }

        function getStepCoords(cur, tar, step) {
            var curX = cur[0];
            var curY = cur[1];
            var tarX = tar[0];
            var tarY = tar[1];
            var xmultiplier;
            var ymultiplier;
            var xdiff;
            var ydiff;
            if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY == curY)) {
                xmultiplier = 1;
                ymultiplier = 0;
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY == curY)) {
                xmultiplier = -1;
                ymultiplier = 0;
            }
            else if ((tarY > curY)&&(tarX == curX)) {
                xmultiplier = 0;
                ymultiplier = 1;
            }
            else if ((tarY < curY)&&(tarX == curX)) {
                xmultiplier = 0;
                ymultiplier = -1;
            }
            else if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY > curY)) {
                xdiff = tarX - curX;
                ydiff = tarY - curY;
                xmultiplier = xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
                ymultiplier = ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY < curY)) {
                xdiff = curX - tarX;
                ydiff = curY - tarY;
                xmultiplier = -(xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
                ymultiplier = -(ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
            }
            else if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY < curY)) {
                xdiff = tarX - curX;
                ydiff = curY - tarY;
                xmultiplier = xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
                ymultiplier = -(ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY > curY)) {
                xdiff = curX - tarX;
                ydiff = tarY - curY;
                xmultiplier = -(xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
                ymultiplier = ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
            }
            var newx = curX + Math.round(step * xmultiplier);
            var newy = curY + Math.round(step * ymultiplier);
            return [newx, newy];
        }

        function updateTarX(canvasid, x) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][4] = x;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateTarY(canvasid, y) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][5] = y;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateCurX(canvasid, x) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][2] = x;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateCurY(canvasid, y) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][3] = y;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateTarAngle(canvasid, angle) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][8] = angle;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function updateCurAngle(canvasid, angle) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][7] = angle;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function getCurAngle(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][7];
        }

        function getTarAngle(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return cobjects[key][8];
        }

        function isMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (cobjects[key][2] == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function isRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (cobjects[key][6] == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function startRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][6] = 1;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stopRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][6] = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function startMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][3] = 1;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stopMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][4] = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function drawSprite(ctx, angle, img, centerX, centerY) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.rotate(angle);
            ctx.drawImage(img, -(img.width / 2), -(img.height / 2));
            ctx.restore();
            return true;
        }

        function rotate(ctx, canvas, angle, img) {
            var rotation = Math.PI * angle / 180;
            var max = Math.max(img.width, img.height);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, max, max);
            drawSprite(ctx, rotation, img, max / 2, max / 2);
            return true;
        }

        function draw(canvasid, imgfile, angle, left, top) {    
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.id = canvasid;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            canvas.appendChild(img);
            img.id = canvas.id + "imgid";
            img.onload = function() {
                var max = Math.max(img.width, img.height);
                canvas.width = canvas.height = max;
                canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = max + "px";
                canvas.style.position = "absolute";
                canvas.style.left = left + "px";
                canvas.style.top = top + "px";
                drawSprite(ctx, 0, img, max / 2, max / 2);
                if ((isset(angle))&&(angle !== 0)) {
                    rotate(ctx, canvas, angle, img);
                }
            };
            img.src = imgfile;
            return true;
        }

        function execMoving(canvasid) {
            var el = typeof canvasid == 'string' ? document.getElementById(canvasid) : canvasid;
            var curX = getCurX(canvasid);
            var curY = getCurY(canvasid);
            var tarX = getTarX(canvasid);
            var tarY = getTarY(canvasid);

            //calculate how often we have to do this in order to determine delay and step later
            var i = 0;
            var loopdone = false;
            var step = 5;
            var loopcurX = curX;
            var loopcurY = curY;
            var loopcoords;
            var loopxdiff;
            var loopydiff;
            while (!(loopdone)) {
                i++;
                loopcoords = getStepCoords([loopcurX, loopcurY], [tarX, tarY], step);
                loopxdiff = Math.max(tarX, loopcoords[0]) - Math.min(tarX, loopcoords[0]);
                loopydiff = Math.max(tarY, loopcoords[1]) - Math.min(tarY, loopcoords[1]);
                if ((loopxdiff <= step)&&(loopydiff <= step)) {
                    loopdone = true;
                }
                else {
                    loopcurX = loopcoords[0];
                    loopcurY = loopcoords[1];
                }
            }

            var delay = 0;
            step = 0;
            var multiplier = 0;
            var stepextra = 5;
            var time;
            if (presstime > latency) { time = presstime - latency; } else { time = presstime; }
            while (delay < 1) {
                multiplier++;
                step = stepextra * multiplier;
                delay = Math.round((time) / (i / multiplier));
            }
            if (delay > 10) { delay = 10; } //ceil delay

            var coords = getStepCoords([curX, curY], [tarX, tarY], step);
            var xPos = coords[0];
            var yPos = coords[1];
            el.style.left = xPos + 'px';
            el.style.top = yPos + 'px';
            updateCurX(canvasid, xPos);
            updateCurY(canvasid, yPos);
            var xdiff = Math.max(tarX, xPos) - Math.min(tarX, xPos);
            var ydiff = Math.max(tarY, yPos) - Math.min(tarY, yPos);
            if ((xdiff <= step)&&(ydiff <= step)) {
                stopMoving(canvasid);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(function() { execMoving(canvasid); }, delay);
            }
            return true;
        }

        function execRotation(canvasid) {
            var curAngle = getCurAngle(canvasid);
            var tarAngle = getTarAngle(canvasid);

            //calcAngles
            var tarAngleCalc;
            var curAngleCalc;
            var calcDiff;
            if (tarAngle > 360) { tarAngleCalc = tarAngle - 360; } else if (tarAngle < 0) { tarAngleCalc = tarAngle + 360; } else { tarAngleCalc = tarAngle; }
            if (curAngle > 360) { curAngleCalc = curAngle - 360; } else if (curAngle < 0) { curAngleCalc = curAngle + 360; } else { curAngleCalc = curAngle; }

            //calcDiff
            if ((tarAngleCalc > 180)&&(curAngleCalc < 180)&&(Math.max(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) - Math.min(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) > 180)) {
                tarAngleCalc = tarAngleCalc - 360;
                calcDiff = Math.max(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) - Math.min(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc);
            }
            else if ((curAngleCalc > 180)&&(tarAngleCalc < 180)&&(Math.max(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) - Math.min(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) > 180)) {
                curAngleCalc = curAngleCalc - 360;
                calcDiff = Math.max(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) - Math.min(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc);
            }
            else {
                calcDiff = Math.max(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc) - Math.min(tarAngleCalc, curAngleCalc);
            }

            //calculate rotation speed
            var changeAngle = 0;
            var rotspeed = 0;
            var time;
            if (presstime > latency) { time = presstime - latency; } else { time = presstime; }
            while (rotspeed < 1) {
                changeAngle++;
                rotspeed = Math.round(time / (calcDiff / changeAngle));
            }

            //rotate
            var angle;
            if ((tarAngle > curAngle)&&(tarAngle - curAngle > 180)) {
                angle = curAngle - changeAngle;
            }
            else if (tarAngle > curAngle) {
                angle = curAngle + changeAngle;
            }
            else if ((tarAngle < curAngle)&&(curAngle - tarAngle > 180)) {
                angle = curAngle + changeAngle;
            }
            else if (tarAngle < curAngle) {
                angle = curAngle - changeAngle;
            }
            if (angle > 360) { angle = angle - 360; } else if (angle < 0) { angle = angle + 360; }
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasid);
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = document.getElementById(canvasid + "imgid");
            rotate(ctx, canvas, angle, img);
            updateCurAngle(canvasid, angle);
            if (getCurAngle(canvasid) != getTarAngle(canvasid)) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    execRotation(canvasid);
                }, rotspeed);
            }
            else {
                stopRotating(canvasid);
            }
            return true;
        }

        function keydown(e) {
            var keynum;
            if (window.event) { // Internet Explorer
                keynum = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) { // Netscape, Firefox and Opera
                keynum = e.which;
            }
            if (keysdown.indexOf(keynum) == -1) {
                keysdown.push(keynum);
            }
            return true;
        }

        function keyup(e) {
            var keynum;
            if (window.event) { // Internet Explorer
                keynum = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) { // Netscape, Firefox and Opera
                keynum = e.which;
            }
            key = keysdown.indexOf(keynum);
            if (key != -1) {
                keysdown.splice(key);
            }
            return true;
        }

        function isDown(keynum) {
            if (keysdown.indexOf(keynum) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function ajaxHandle1(explode) { //move existing canvas object
            var canvasid = explode[1];
            var x = parseFloat(explode[2]);
            var y = parseFloat(explode[3]);
            if ((getCurX(canvasid) != x)||(getCurY(canvasid) != y)) {
                if (isMoving(canvasid)) {
                    updateTarX(canvasid, x);
                    updateTarY(canvasid, y);
                }
                else {
                    updateTarX(canvasid, x);
                    updateTarY(canvasid, y);
                    startMoving(canvasid);
                    execMoving(canvasid);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        function ajaxHandle2(explode) { //create new canvas object
            var canvasid = explode[1];
            var imgfile = explode[2];
            var x = parseFloat(explode[3]);
            var y = parseFloat(explode[4]);
            var angle = parseFloat(explode[5]);
            var rotation = Math.PI * angle / 180;
            draw(canvasid, imgfile, rotation);
            cobjects.push([canvasid, 0, x, y, x, y, 0, angle, angle]); //register canvas object - [canvasid, moving, curX, curY, tarX, tarY, rotating, curAngle, tarAngle]
        }

        function ajaxHandle3(explode) { //rotate existing canvas object
            var canvasid = explode[1];
            var angle = parseFloat(explode[2]);
            if (getCurAngle(canvasid) != angle) { //if the new angle is different
                if (isRotating(canvasid)) {
                    updateTarAngle(canvasid, angle);
                }
                else {
                    updateTarAngle(canvasid, angle);
                    startRotating(canvasid);
                    execRotation(canvasid);
                }
            }
        }

        function handleAjaxResponse(response) {
            var commands = response.split("@");
            var command;
            var explode;
            var type;
            for (var i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) { // loop every handler command to execute it's type of action, commands are separated by an @ character
                command = commands[i];
                explode = command.split("#"); // explode the attributes of this command, separated by an # character
                type = parseFloat(explode[0]);
                if (type == 1) { //move existing canvas object
                    ajaxHandle1(explode);
                }
                else if (type == 2) { //create new canvas object
                    ajaxHandle2(explode);
                }
                else if (type == 3) { //rotate existing canvas object
                    ajaxHandle3(explode);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        function doAjax(get) {
            var oldLatencyTime = new Date();
            oldLatencyTime = oldLatencyTime.getTime();
            if (!(isset(get))) {
                get = "";
            }
            if ((getAjaxResTimeDiff() < ajaxivtime)&&(get === "")) {
                return false;
            }
            var xmlHttpReq = false;
            try { // Firefox, Opera 8.0+ and Safari
                xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e) { // Internet Explorer
                try {
                    xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    try {
                        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX. Please use an AJAX compatible browser.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlHttpReq.open('GET', 'handler.php' + get, true);
            xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
                    updateLatency(oldLatencyTime);
                    var response = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
                    if ((isset(response))&&(response !== "")) {
                        handleAjaxResponse(response);
                    }
                }
            };
            xmlHttpReq.send(null);
            return true;
        }

        function keyinput() { //keycodes: 87 = w, 68 = d, 65 = a
            if (getPressTimeDiff() > presstime) {
                if ((isDown(87))&&(isDown(68))&&(!(isDown(65)))) {
                    setOldPress();
                    doAjax("?move=f&rotate=r");
                }
                else if ((isDown(87))&&(isDown(65))&&(!(isDown(68)))) {
                    setOldPress();
                    doAjax("?move=f&rotate=l");
                }
                else if ((isDown(87))&&(!(isDown(68)))&&(!(isDown(65)))) {
                    setOldPress();
                    doAjax("?move=f");
                }
                else if ((isDown(68))&&(!(isDown(65)))) {
                    setOldPress();
                    doAjax("?rotate=r");
                }
                else if ((isDown(65))&&(!(isDown(68)))) {
                    setOldPress();
                    doAjax("?rotate=l");
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        //init intervals
        var iv_ajax = setInterval(function() { doAjax(); }, ajaxivtime); //ajax handler interval
        var iv_keypress = setInterval(function() { keyinput(); }, keypressivtime); //keypress fire interval

        //register event handlers
        document.onkeydown = function(event) { keydown(event); };
        document.onkeyup = function(event) { keyup(event); };
        document.onkeypress = function(event) { keycheck(event); };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: white;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 300px;">W: accelerate.<br />A: rotate left.<br />D: rotate right.</div></body>
</html>
```

As you can probably notice, even if your latency (see title) is lower then 50ms, the shuttle will now and then "shock" or lag while moving/rotating. Because I wanted to find out what is causing the problem, I remade the whole thing to a client side version (without ajax).

You can check it out here: [http://ajax.uptowar.com/test5/index.php][2]

This is the source of the client side remake:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
session_start();
$_SESSION['playerid'] = "";
echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ajax test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <meta name="audience" content="all" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">     
        //vars
        var keypressivtime = 50; //interval at which keyinput is handled
        var presstime = 150; //howlong a button should be hold down for 1 event fire

        //init
        var cobjects = []; //array for all canvas objects
        var keysdown = []; //array for what keys are down at a specific moment
        var oldpress = 0; //press init
        var latency = 0; //client side

        //functions
        function isset() {
            var a = arguments;
            var l = a.length;
            var i = 0;
            if (l === 0) { 
                return false;
            }
            while (i != l) {
                if (typeof(a[i]) == 'undefined' || a[i] === null) { 
                    return false; 
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        function getStepCoords(cur, tar, step) {
            var curX = cur[0];
            var curY = cur[1];
            var tarX = tar[0];
            var tarY = tar[1];
            var xmultiplier;
            var ymultiplier;
            var xdiff;
            var ydiff;
            if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY == curY)) {
                xmultiplier = 1;
                ymultiplier = 0;
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY == curY)) {
                xmultiplier = -1;
                ymultiplier = 0;
            }
            else if ((tarY > curY)&&(tarX == curX)) {
                xmultiplier = 0;
                ymultiplier = 1;
            }
            else if ((tarY < curY)&&(tarX == curX)) {
                xmultiplier = 0;
                ymultiplier = -1;
            }
            else if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY > curY)) {
                xdiff = tarX - curX;
                ydiff = tarY - curY;
                xmultiplier = xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
                ymultiplier = ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY < curY)) {
                xdiff = curX - tarX;
                ydiff = curY - tarY;
                xmultiplier = -(xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
                ymultiplier = -(ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
            }
            else if ((tarX > curX)&&(tarY < curY)) {
                xdiff = tarX - curX;
                ydiff = curY - tarY;
                xmultiplier = xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
                ymultiplier = -(ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
            }
            else if ((tarX < curX)&&(tarY > curY)) {
                xdiff = curX - tarX;
                ydiff = tarY - curY;
                xmultiplier = -(xdiff / (xdiff + ydiff));
                ymultiplier = ydiff / (xdiff + ydiff);
            }
            var newx = curX + Math.round(step * xmultiplier);
            var newy = curY + Math.round(step * ymultiplier);
            return [newx, newy];
        }

        function drawSprite(ctx, angle, img, centerX, centerY) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.rotate(angle);
            ctx.drawImage(img, -(img.width / 2), -(img.height / 2));
            ctx.restore();
            return true;
        }

        function rotate(ctx, canvas, angle, img) {
            var rotation = Math.PI * angle / 180;
            var max = Math.max(img.width, img.height);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, max, max);
            drawSprite(ctx, rotation, img, max / 2, max / 2);
            return true;
        }

        function searchcobjects(canvasid) {
            indexes = cobjects.length - 1;
            i = 0;
            while (i <= indexes) {
                if (cobjects[i][0] == canvasid) {
                    return i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        function isMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (cobjects[key][1] == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function isRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else if (cobjects[key][6] == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function startRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][6] = 1;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stopRotating(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][6] = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function startMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][1] = 1;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stopMoving(canvasid) {
            var key = searchcobjects(canvasid);
            if (key == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                cobjects[key][1] = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function stepxy(steppixels, angle) { //steppixels is the total amount of pixels to be shared between x and y depending on the angle
            var xmultiplier;
            if ((angle < 0)||(angle > 360)) {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((angle === 0)||(angle == 360)) {
                xmultiplier = 0;
                ymultiplier = -1;
            }
            else if ((angle > 0)&&(angle < 91)) {
                xmultiplier = angle / 90;
                ymultiplier = -(1 - (angle / 90));
            }
            else if ((angle > 90)&&(angle < 181)) {
                xmultiplier = 1 - ((angle - 90) / 90);
                ymultiplier = (angle - 90) / 90;
            }
            else if ((angle > 180)&&(angle < 271)) {
                xmultiplier = -((angle - 180) / 90);
                ymultiplier = 1 - ((angle - 180) / 90);
            }
            else if ((angle > 270)&&(angle < 361)) {
                xmultiplier = -(1 - ((angle - 270) / 90));
                ymultiplier = -((angle - 270) / 90);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            var xstep = Math.round(steppixels * xmultiplier);
            var ystep = Math.round(steppixels * ymultiplier);
            var arr = [xstep, ystep];
            return arr;
        }

        function getPressTimeDiff() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            curtime = curtime.getTime();
            return curtime - oldpress;
        }

        function setOldPress() {
            var curtime = new Date();
            oldpress = curtime.getTime();
            return true;
        }

        function isDown(keynum) {
            if (keysdown.indexOf(keynum) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
```

Comment: how's the client side remake doing ?

Comment: andyk : isn't it doing fine? you can see for yourself: http://ajax.uptowar.com/test5/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the biggest issue you are running into here is that you have made the movement of the sprite synchronous with an asynchronous operation.  Both your draw cycle and your movement actions should be decoupled from the AJAX response.  Record all of the movement of the sprite client side and send differences to the server.  The server can validate the differences to ensure that the sprite has not moved farther than it should have.  If the server and the client disagree about the position of the sprite above some threshold the sprite can be moved to a position that is correct. In general the server and the client should agree that the sprite can have moved from the last known point to the new point.

```
Here is some very crude psudo code to illustrate the concept.

Client:
Packet = {startPoint:{x:1, y:1}, endpoint:{x:5 y:7});
sendPacket(Packet);

Server:
If(abs(Packet.startPoint - Packet.endPoint) > minPoint){
    fixPoint.x = Packet.endPoint.x – minPoint.x;
fixPoint.y = Packet.endPoint.y – minPoint.y;
    Return {moveValid: false, fixPoint: fixPoint}
}else{
    Return (moveValid: true)
}
```

This will work well in compensating for simple latency and will also detect cheating by the client.  If there is extreme latency you will end up with frequent “teleporting” of the sprite especially if the requests start getting processed out of order when the latency is greater that the frequency you are sending requests.
Most online games use sockets directly and can send much lighter packets than HTTP which you are stuck with in JavaScript, so you will need to explore the bounds of the concept to see where the thresholds will land with JavaScript and AJAX.